# Simple JSP - Attribute invalid for tag according to TLD

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

**My project in eclipse -**

[image]

I get the error below when I run MyTagUser.jsp - `HTTP Status 500 - /jsp/MyTagUser.jsp(14,0) Attribute subTitle invalid for tag Header according to TLD`

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/MyTagUser.jsp(14,0) Attribute subTitle 
invalid for tag Header according to TLD

org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)...etc.
```

**Snippet from Header.jsp -**

```
<body>
<img src="../images/java_logo.gif"><br>
<em><strong> ${subTitle} </strong></em> <br>
</body>
```

**Snippet from MyTagUser.jsp -**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="myTags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<myTags:Header  subTitle="Java is the best !!!" />
JSP and Servlets.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to follow along with _Head First Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition_. A few pages later they will talk about the solution that @Borat Sagdiyev gave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use the attribute directive in your Header.tag file as show below -

```
<body>
<%@ attribute name="subTitle" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<img src="../images/java_logo.gif"><br>
<em><strong> ${subTitle} </strong></em> <br>
</body>
```

Comment: I found `rtexprvalue="true"` to be the critical part when I encountered the OP's error trying to pass an attribute from one custom tag to another.  Both had been correctly declaring the expected attributes, but without specifying `rtexprvalue="true"` it would error out regardless.

Answer (score 0):

First Solution:

It seems, you wanted to include header area in your jsp. But it's wrong way.

You should create a header.jsp and then include header.jsp into your MyTagUser.jsp and they should be under the WEB-INF directory(or its sub-directory).

Including method : <%@ include file="WEB-INF/tags/header.jsp"> use this code in MyTagUser.jsp

Second Solution :

in your tag file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> core jstl taglib if necessary

<%@ attribute name="subtitle" required="true" %> this is subTitle attribute
```

you should define attribute(s). check out http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html

Comment: I want to create a Header.tag file and NOT Header.jsp which will be used by my JSP. How do I do that ?

Comment: it is in second solution.