# Attribute modelAttribute invalid for tag form according to TLD

Tags: spring, forms, jsp

I am trying to create a form:form but every time I have the model Attributr tag I get the following error!

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> /WEB-INF/views/start.jsp (line: 17, column: 0) Attribute modelAttribute invalid for tag form according to TLD

Here is my JSP code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Official Sars-CoV3 Test Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="addResults" modelAttribute="results">
<label for="tTN">TTN: </label><br>
<input type="text" id="tTN" name="tTN"><br>
<label for="fullname">Full Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname">
<label for="email">Email:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<label for="age">Age:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<label for="gender">Please select Gender:</label>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form:form > 
<a href="login">Admin Login </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504719/simple-jsp-attribute-invalid-for-tag-according-to-tld/23506636

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple JSP - Attribute invalid for tag according to TLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504719/simple-jsp-attribute-invalid-for-tag-according-to-tld)

Comment: I don't understand the answers to those questions, as it's a different tag in a different place. Does anyone have any idea?